# Rubyzip - possible to set extraction folder?

Tags: ruby, zip, directory, rubyzip, self-extracting

My problem is that I need to set the root extraction folder for a zip-file I'm generating by using Rubyzip. The zip-file will be opened in Windows as self-extractable. Is this option available in Rubyzip? Or is this a value that is stored in the Windows registry and used by the integrated zip-functionality in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will face another problem, as RubyZip itself doesn't make self-extractable archives.

There are possibilities to combine a zip-extractor binary with your archived data into extractable .exe. And I guess there are no zip-extractors to hold default path for extraction destination, as there is dialog prompting for.

Have a look, this thread can help http://groups.google.com/group/brighton-ruby/browse_thread/thread/89b2e9ac4dfbed3b?pli=1

Regards, bv